# Open .plf files on win 10

Tags: windows-10

Any ideas on how to open a .plf file? (As below)

MINIKIT_Neo_2_HD_Update_ENGB (2).plf

It is to upgrade a Bluetooth in-car phone device by Parrot USA

Comment: did any install instructions come with it that you have tried and can share?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to open the file to update the device. Here, I will list the guide I found on [Parrot Support Page](http://www.parrot.com/usa/support/parrot-minikit-neo-2-hd/).

1. Parrot MINIKIT Neo 2 HD software updates are performed using a
   computer via USB. Click on your flag to download the corresponding
   update file. The downloaded .plf file corresponds to the update file
   to be installed on your Parrot product. A .plf file is not to be
   mistaken with a .pdf file (which can be opened using Adobe Reader).
2. Turn the Parrot MINIKIT Neo 2 HD on Connect the Parrot MINIKIT Neo 2
   HD to your computer (PC or Mac) using a USB/Micro-USB cable.
3. Press the jogwheel and select Updating.

   - The Parrot MINIKIT says "Waiting for update". The lights turn red and green.
   - (PC) A pop-up window appears on your computer screen. If not, go to "My Computer" and open the MINIKIT folder.
   - (Mac) The MINIKIT folder appears on your Desktop.
4. Open the MINIKIT folder.
5. Drag and drop the previously downloaded update file into the
   MINIKIT folder, like you would do with a USB flash drive. Wait until
   the transfer is complete.
6. Eject then disconnect the Parrot MINIKIT
   Neo 2 HD from your computer.

   - The following message appears: "Device can now be safely removed from the system".
   - The Parrot MINIKIT Neo 2 HD says "Update in progress, please wait". The red light flashes.
7. Wait until the Parrot MINIKIT Neo 2 HD
   reboots.

   - Once the Parrot MINIKIT Neo 2 HD has rebooted, the Parrot MINIKIT Neo 2 HD says "Software updated".

Comment: Yes, found that, perhaps it is the actual unit? as the 'jog wheel' doesn't trigger the update sequence, and the file won't drag and drop either......

Comment: What I suspect is the format of the USb device. What is it currently? Sometimes the devices does not understand all formats.